# How to calculate maximal allowed batch_size?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, memory-management, batch-processing

I have a function which creates arrays from a dataframe and needs some more space during processing.
Therefore I implemented a batchwise parameter, which iterates over the dataframe and selects an area of around `batch_len = 1000`  rows, preprocesses them, and concatenates them to my result numpy array.

to not take endlessly small batches I'd like to make a calculating function that determines, how much rows (`batch_len`) we are allowed to preprocess at a time.

therefore I need to know, how big numpy arrays are?
is there a (more or less) constant size?

What do I always know: amount of *rows & columns*

I mostly calculate with float32 or float64 (but I'm willing to do always act as if its float64 to make this function more simple)

Comment: You need to know how big numpy arrays are, or your pandas df chunks?

Comment: @anon01 its more about the numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the size of the array in bytes. This can be done with the `.nbytes` attribute of an array:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((10, 10, 10))
print('{} KB'.format(x.nbytes / 1024))
```

```
7.8125 KB
```

Next, you need to define batches so every batch can fit into your RAM. Note that some processing function can sometimes duplicate arrays in the memory, so you may want to monitor your memory use as the Python script executes with the `top` program (on Linux like OS) or `htop`.

Comment: my question is more about ram (at least I guess, correct me please).

when I create a numpy array of 100.000 rows x 10 columns of float64 (==8Byte) elements.
will the array be 8.000.000 Byte big?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to RAM (edited). And, yes (you can calculate the size this way, or use the `nbytes` attribute, it will return the same value).